# How to pull NodeJs module class list?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to build a code generator that maps an existing template file to correlating class files. They all come from a single module, but I am not seeing how to read the class / module list within that module.

I basically need to do what intellisense is doing to read the module info.

How do I get to this information in the module via code?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to build a code generator that maps an existing template
> file to correlating class files. They all come from a single module,
> but I am not seeing how to read the class / module list within that
> module.
>
> I basically need to do what intellisense is doing to read the module
> info.
>
> How do I get to this information in the module via code?

It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, but you might want to use a library that generates an abstract syntax tree (AST) like [`espree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/espree).

This question is a bit unclear to me. While it's clear that you want to be able to read the contents of a module programmatically, it's unclear if you want to retrieve function signatures, source code, a list of constructors only, or what.

You can get an array of every property on a module with `Object.keys(module)` (although there are limitations). You can check to see which of those properties are functions by checking `typeof module.property === 'function'`.

You can get more information programmatically, of course, such as the source code of the function by running `.toString()` on the function. But there are a million things that can go wrong. So I'll repeat what I started with: You'll might want to use a library that generates an abstract syntax tree (AST) like [`espree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/espree) rather than trying to implement this yourself.

Comment: I am looking to use code generation with existing YAML templates to create properly typed class properties. In my code generation I have a third party utility that is able to read the template and identify the proper types, but in my generated code I need to write out the full import path.